# Are gravitons suggested as the cause of matter curving space?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, spacetime, curvature, carrier-particles

My understand is that GR says that mass curves space but it does not say ***why*** or how this occurs. Is the idea of gravitons that they are the entities that actually affect space?

Comment: Newton’s Second Law doesn’t say why acceleration is force divided by mass. That doesn’t stop it from being useful.

Answer (score 2):

> My understand is that GR says that mass curves space

More precisely, GR says that mass, energy, and momentum (technically, the [stress-energy tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress%E2%80%93energy_tensor)) curves **spacetime**. It is very important that both space and time are unified and both experience curvature -- in fact, in some sense, gravitational effects you are used to (like an apple falling from a tree) are associated with curvature in time. Additionally, small particles follow geodesics in spacetime.

> but it does not say why or how this occurs.

In terms of *how* this occurs, GR is very specific. There is a precise relationship -- the Einstein field equations -- that tells us exactly how much and in which ways spacetime is curved, based on how much stress-energy is present.

Now, "*why*" can be a very tricky question in physics. There is a [great video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=36GT2zI8lVA&t=1s) by physicist Richard Feynman on this topic I recommend watching. Typically, the answer to a "why" question involves deriving or explaining some equation or phenomena in terms of some more basic principles.

In the realm of established physics, GR (and Einstein's field equations) are not derived from anything else. They simply *are*. They are part of the foundational assumptions that we build the rest of the framework of physics on top of.

People often speculate that GR can be derived from some deeper principles. However, often "space" and "time" are emergent concepts in these speculative theories. So rather than "explain how mass curves spacetime", these theories would do something like explain how spacetime emerges from something deeper and why it obeys the Einstein field equations. For example, in Verlinde's [entropic gravity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropic_gravity), gravity would emerge in some kind of limit of a large number of smaller degrees of freedom (exactly what these are, are a mystery). In string theory, different excitations in loops of string correspond to different particles, and in a low energy limit the interactions collections of strings behave like the spacetime in GR.

"Gravitons" are a way of understanding quantum gravity in a limit when interactions are weak. Understanding consistent interactions between gravitons is one way to discover the Einstein field equations (eg, see Feynman's [Lectures on Gravitation](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201627345)). However, this explanation is more subtle than a mechanical picture like "gravitons cause changes in spacetime." It is more of a mathematical consistency argument that a spin-2 particle like the graviton must obey equations like Einstein's field equations in an appropriate limit.